# In UITableview array shows null thread SIGABRT error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to iOS development. I am developing my project which is fully based on XML parsing from url. I parsed XML data and stored in an array but I am not able to display the arraydata  in `UITableView`.

Here is my code.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    eventarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    xmlParserObject = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
    [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParserObject parse];
    for (int i =0; i<[rssOutputData count]; i++) {
        Eventlist *log = [rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i];
        eventid = log.id;
        NSLog(@"%d",eventid);
        Invit = log.eventname;
        NSLog(@"%@",Invit);
    }
    [rssOutputData release];
    [connection release];
    [tblView reloadData];
}
```

My array prints the value here, but how to pass this array data in `UITableView`. I tried this but I didn't get data in table view.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"eventCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell= [[tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        Eventlist *msglist = [eventarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = msglist.eventname;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        UIButton *viewmoreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        viewmoreButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);
        [viewmoreButton setTitle:@"View More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:viewmoreButton];
        [viewmoreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(viewMore:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: btw: If you are new to Objective-C start learning it using ARC. This will prevent a lot if headaches.

Comment: Now to your problem. Did you set yourself as the delegate for your table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you are storing your data in `rssOutputData`, but you are calling `[rssOutputData release];` at the end of `connectionDidFinishLoading`. You are probably throwing out your data there.

It looks like `eventArray` never has anything added to it. That will cause a crash if you try to access an index that doesn't exist.

try changing your `for` loop to:

```
for (int i =0; i<[rssOutputData count]; i++) {
Eventlist *log = [rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i];
eventid = log.id;
NSLog(@"%d",eventid);
Invit = log.eventname;
NSLog(@"%@",Invit);

[eventArray addObject:log];
}
```

Comment: Nick Galasso: Hi Sir i modified my code as u suggested but still i cannot able to view data in uitableview Still it prints null in the console. after calling eventarray in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1):

Thats not the proper way to load the data in tableView(when parsing xml).Because you're completly not sure whether you will get the data immediately you parse it(for the big xml files).

Implement [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008632-CH1-SW4)'s delegate method called,

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
//here your [tableView reloadData] goes...
}
```

Sent by the parser object to the delegate when it has successfully completed parsing.

Answer (score 0):

As much as i understand your code, i didn't see you populating your eventarray because in cellForRowAtIndexPath you are fetching some record from that array and trying to display values in cell so definitly it would be empty at that time.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow this link for create sample tableview.replace the array data instead of constant data with your response data array.After getting your array values use [tableview reloadData];

Comment: You forgot to add the link.